# Is this a valid procedure?

Tags: calculus

Suppose I have $ \int f'(u)\ g'(x)\ du $, and I know that $f(u)=g'(x)$. The question is, in order to solve the above integral, can I replace $g'(x)$ in the integrand by $f(u)$, such that $ \int f'(u)\ g'(x)\ du =  \int f'(u)\ f(u)\ du = \frac {(f(u))^2} {2}+C$

Comment: Sounds fine to me.  Don't forget "$+C$" in the final answer.

Comment: How can $g'(x)=f(u)$? They are different variables...

Comment: $g'(x)=f(u)$ could be true if $x$ and $u$ are related by a function such that $u=g(x)$

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you're gven that $g'(x)=f(u)$, let $t=f(u)$. Then $dt=f'(u)du$ and by the substitution rule,

$\int f(u)f'(u)du=\int tdt=t^2/2+C=(f(u))^2/2+C$.

Answer (score 0):

If, as you appear to assume implicitly, $x=h(u)$ for some function $h$ and $g'\bigl( h(u)\bigr)=f(u)$ for all values of $u$, then indeed

$$\int_a^b f'(u) g'\bigl(h(u)\bigr) du = \int_a^b f'(u) f(u) du =\bigl(f^2(b)-f^2(a)\bigr)/2.$$